# Multiple Modals not closing when I click on the X button

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

The modals that I have set up for my website are opening on clicking the respective div elements and they're closing as well when clicking outside the modals but they're not closing on clicking the 'X' buttons, except for the very first modal.

```
{% for i in range(anime_name|length)%}

    <!-- The Modal -->

        <div id = "more-details1" class = "modal">

        <!-- More details content -->

            <div class = "more-details-content">
                <div class = "modal-header">
                        <span class = "close" id = "close_{{i}}">&times;</span>
                            <p> {{ anime_name[0] }} </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "modal-body">
                            <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
                            <p>Some other text...</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
                        
        </div> 
                
{% endfor %}

{% for i in range(anime_name|length)%}

    <!-- The Modal -->

        <div id = "more-details2" class = "modal">

            <!-- More details content -->

            <div class = "more-details-content">
                    <div class = "modal-header">
                            <span class = "close" id = "close_{{i}}">&times;</span>
                                <p> {{ anime_name[1] }} </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "modal-body">
                                <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
                                <p>Some other text...</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
                        
    </div> 
                
{% endfor %}
```

```
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  }

.more-details-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
  }

  /* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
  }
  
  @keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
  }

  /* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #f6e8d6;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

.close:hover, .close:focus {
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #b83333;
    color: #f6e8d6;
  }

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}
```

```
var modal1 = document.getElementById("more-details1")
var btn1 = document.querySelector(".anime-holder_0")
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// var span1 = document.getElementById("close_0");

var modal2 = document.getElementById("more-details2")
var btn2 = document.querySelector(".anime-holder_1")
// var span2 = document.getElementById("close_1");

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if(btn1.contains(event.target)){
        modal1.style.display = "block";
        } else {
        if (!modal1.contains(event.target) && modal1.style.display === "block" ||  span.contains(event.target)) {
                    modal1.style.display = "none";
                }
    }
        if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
        }

    if(btn2.contains(event.target)){
        modal2.style.display = "block";
        } else {
                if (!modal2.contains(event.target) && modal2.style.display === "block" ||  span.contains(event.target)) {
                    modal2.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
        if (event.target == modal2) {
                modal2.style.display = "none";
        }

}
```

I'm using the jinja template to access the values from my dataframe in the modal section but also because I tried giving individual IDs to each 'close' aka 'X' button through "close_{{i}}" (as that seems to be working when I'm accessing the 'anime-holder_0' and 'anime-holder_1' in btn1 and btn2 through 'anime-holder_{{i}}') so I tried doing that here too with different 'span' for each modal but that didn't work as the multiple modals didn't close on clicking 'X' except for the first one.

It could be because of the many conditions being given in the windows.onclick = function(event) {} but having a seperate function for each modal doesn't work either because it overrides the previous one.

I'm not sure what's the reason for this problem but I'm just looking for a way to close multiple modals by clicking on their 'X' buttons AND clicking outside the modals themselves (Hopefully without having to use Bootstrap).

Comment: why not just use standard [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement)/[Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal) for this?

Comment: @MisterJojo I did try that out but I just can't seem to get them closed by clicking on the close button. It might work for one modal but it's not working for more than one. Not sure why

Comment: you have to learn about event delegation, there is multiple questions/answers allready on this topic here.